# Wordpress New Post Page (Gutenberg) Fails after Upgrading to 6.4.3

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

- I deactivated all plugins.
- I also changed theme to default theme.
- I manually downloaded WordPress again, and deleted existing files
  (wp-admin, wp-includes, and root files)
- Browser cache & cookies deleted.

I still get those errors on console and white screen is shown on browser.  If I disable Gutenberg editor, page works fine.

I'm also using 6.4.3 version on my other sites, on the same server without issue.

```
private-apis.min.js?ver=11cb2ebaa70a9f1f0ab5:2 Uncaught Error: You tried to opt-in to unstable APIs as module "@wordpress/patterns". This feature is only for JavaScript modules shipped with WordPress core. Please do not use it in plugins and themes as the unstable APIs will be removed without a warning. If you ignore this error and depend on unstable features, your product will inevitably break on one of the next WordPress releases.
    at s (private-apis.min.js?ver=11cb2ebaa70a9f1f0ab5:2:912)
    at patterns.min.js?ver=efcce5c1b2c28e8b2865:2:2095
    at patterns.min.js?ver=efcce5c1b2c28e8b2865:2:8848
s @ private-apis.min.js?ver=11cb2ebaa70a9f1f0ab5:2
(anonymous) @ patterns.min.js?ver=efcce5c1b2c28e8b2865:2
(anonymous) @ patterns.min.js?ver=efcce5c1b2c28e8b2865:2

16:00:57.640 react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReusableBlocksMenuItems')
    at editor.min.js?ver=5abe10197275cf7808ee:12:144597
    at wt (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:47637)
    at vr (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:56452)
    at js (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:121453)
    at wl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88659)
    at bl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88587)
    at yl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88450)
    at il (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85274)
    at fl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85661)
    at Nn (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:32474)
ar @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
t.callback @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
tt @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
Jr @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
Zr @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
Gr @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
(anonymous) @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
xl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
fl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
Nn @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
(anonymous) @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
setTimeout (async)
s @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
i @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
(anonymous) @ edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
__unstableMarkListeningStores @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
l @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
ze @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
Je @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
ja @ edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7
wt @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
js @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
wl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
bl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
yl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ol @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
v @ react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ce @ react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10

16:00:57.640 react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ReusableBlocksMenuItems')
    at editor.min.js?ver=5abe10197275cf7808ee:12:144597
    at wt (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:47637)
    at vr (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:56452)
    at js (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:121453)
    at wl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88659)
    at bl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88587)
    at yl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:88450)
    at il (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85274)
    at fl (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:85661)
    at Nn (react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:32474)
(anonymous) @ editor.min.js?ver=5abe10197275cf7808ee:12
wt @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
vr @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
js @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
wl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
bl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
yl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
il @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
fl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
Nn @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
(anonymous) @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
setTimeout (async)
s @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
i @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
(anonymous) @ edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
__unstableMarkListeningStores @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:2
l @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
(anonymous) @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
ze @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
Je @ data.min.js?ver=dc5f255634f3da29c8d5:9
ja @ edit-post.min.js?ver=6720d8a86f225f3ce492:7
wt @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
js @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
wl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
bl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
yl @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ol @ react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
v @ react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10
ce @ react.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10

16:00:57.731 plugin.min.js?ver=49110-20201110:1 Deprecated TinyMCE API call: <target>.onNodeChange.add(..)
```

Comment: Are you using the WordPress REST API?

Comment: Yes. Problem is solved when I installed the Gutenberg plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I installed [the Gutenberg plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/), and the problem is solved.